# How do I insert a string before the largest change in a git commit

Tags: git

I have a Markdown document and I want to insert an anchor with an ID so that when it's converted to HTML I can scroll immediately to the biggest change (which will usually be the final change of the commit - most of the changes are big appends with earlier stuff being typo corrections).

I tried checking out `HEAD~1`, appending the anchor tag, stashing it, checking out `HEAD` and then popping the stash but that just resulted in the usual merge conflict mess.

Comment: So you're trying to identify the largest change in that commit so you could modify the file to add an anchor at the start of that change?

Comment: Yes.  Essentially an `<a id="todays-date"></a>` prior to the new content.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a tool, that scans a diff (generated by `git diff` or `git show` or ...) and spots the chunk with the most modified lines.

All diff chunks are indicated by a line looking like :

```
@@ -148,28 +170,85 @@
```

In the above line, `148` and `170` are line numbers (referring to "the lineno in the initial file" and "the lineno in the final file"),
the amount of changes is indicated by `28` and `85` (rougly meaning : diff computed that you can apply a patch that deletes 28 lines and adds 85 lines).

---

You may either take the last mentioned chunk, and use the line number of the last chunk :

```
git show -p -- MyFile.md | grep "^@@ -" | tail -1
```

or process all mentioned chunks, and write a script to print the lineno of the "biggest chunk".

---

The way chunks are grouped together is influenced by the `-U<count>` option (number of context lines), try to toggle that knob (try `git diff/git show` with `-U1`, `-U2`, `-U5` ...) to see what value fits your use case the best.